# image saved in mysql database change their size

Tags: php, android

I go to google image and i choosed one image and save it to my computer. i go to emulator and go to google image and save the same image to gallery of Emulator Genymotion.

using this php script, i save to mysql database this image using form.html.

```html
<?php
echo ini_get( 'file_uploads' );

if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
 echo '<p>Please Select Image to Upload</p>';
 }
else
 {
 try {
 upload();
 }
 catch(Exception $e)
 {
 echo '<h4>'.$e->getMessage().'</h4>';
 }
 }

function upload(){
 $imgfp = fopen($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
 print_r($_FILES);
 
 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=othmane", 'root', '');

 $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image,image_type) VALUES (?,'php')");

 $stmt->bindParam(1, $imgfp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

 $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

image saved in mysql, its size is: **30 Kio**

now i try to save the same image tooken from the same link (google image) and i try to save it via android apps and this is the php script which is the mediator between mysql and the android apps :

```html
<?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  
  $image = $_POST['image'];
  
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane")or die(mysqli_error($con));
  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image,image_type) VALUES (?,'android')";
  
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
  
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$image);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  
  $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
  
  if($check == 1){
   echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
  }else{
   echo "Error Uploading Image";
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
 }else{
  echo "Error";
 }
 ?>
```

in the android apps i encode the image to string using base64 :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
```

Image saved in mysql, now its size is **90Kio** ! why ? and i don't want the images to take a lot of memory in my database. how to avoid that

Comment: Don't save images and files in the database. Use the filesystem.

Comment: so this is the recommended way to deal with images in android apps ?

Comment: It's the recommended way everywhere.

Comment: base64 encoded images would be around 37% larger

Comment: so can we save image from gallery of emulator to database without base64 encoding ?